# cannot found "KeyValueInputFormat" in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am newbie to Hadoop but have read the Yahoo tutorial on that and have already written a few  mapReduce jobs. All my previous works used TextInputFormat but I now need to change that to KeyValueInputFormat. The problem is that KeyValueInputFormat.class cannot be found in hadoop 0.20.2?

I am attaching my code below (It is the word count example with only input format being changed)

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount {

  public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      String line = value.toString();
      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
      while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        output.collect(word, one);
      }
        }
      } 
    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
          int sum = 0;
          while (values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get();
          }
          output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
        conf.setJobName("wordcount");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(keyValueInputFormat.class);  //The modified input format
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(conf);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is KeyValueTextInputFormat in org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.

Some of the old tutorials are based on older versions of Hadoop API. I recommend that you go through some of the newer tutorials.

This is what I get when I do go to source on KeyValueTextInputFormat.

```
package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;

public class KeyValueTextInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, Text> {

public KeyValueTextInputFormat() {
    //compiled code
    throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");
}

protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {
    //compiled code
    throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");
}

public RecordReader<Text, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit genericSplit,     TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException {
    //compiled code
    throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");
}
}
```

Comment: thanks. I went through your newer suggested tutorial. It is the newer version and uses apache.hadoop.mapreduce rather than the older apache.hadoop.mapred. I believe that i should use "  job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);" to set the input format. but it still throws error. any suggestion?

Comment: I edited my answer. Please look in org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input package.

Comment: thanks Deepak. there is no KeyValueTextInputFormat in org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input in Hadoop 0.20.2? I checked on my computer and also on the hadoop 0.20.2 API at http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/

Comment: I have edited the answer above. I am using KeyValueTextInputFormat in my code. It compiles and runs without any issues.

Comment: @DeepakKapoor The link is dead